# Are the new typesafe enums defined to begin at 0?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

Given the following C++11 code

```
enum class Foods {
  Apple,
  Pear,
  Banana
};
```

will

```
std::cout << (unsigned int)Foods::Apple << std::endl;
```

output 0?

This is true for MSVC 2012 and gcc 4.7.0 however I'm more interested in what the C++11 standard specifies we may rely on. That is, can portable code depend on enumerations defaulting to 0 for the value of the first item?

Comment: If you care about their integer representation then why are you using typesafe enums?

Comment: @Pubby, as to not pollute the namespace unnecessarily. Typesafe enums are also properly scoped. Aside from that, I'm more curious than anything else.

Comment: Ok, three good answers all saying the same thing. I upvoted all of them, now which do I accept! I guess I'll accept whichever is most fleshed out by tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are. It's in §7.2/2:

> [...] If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.

This section covers both `enum class` declarations and regular `enum` declarations

Answer (score 6):

The standard doesn't make a distinction between scoped and unscoped enumerations when it comes to the value of the first enumerator that doesn't specify an initializer.

From §7.2/2 **[dcl.enum]**

> The enumeration type declared with an *enum-key* of only `enum` is an
>   unscoped enumeration, and its *enumerators* are *unscoped enumerators*.
>   The *enum-keys* `enum class` and `enum struct` are semantically equivalent;
>   an enumeration type declared with one of these is a *scoped
>   enumeration*, and its *enumerators* are *scoped enumerators*. [...] **If the
>   first *enumerator* has no *initializer*, the value of the corresponding
>   constant is zero**. [...]

Answer (score 5):

The initialization for the enum values didn't change: Unless you give a different initial value, they will start with zero and count up from the previous value. The relevant section is in 7.2 [dcl.enum] paragraph 2:

> If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.